# Is there another way to only get last loaded data using while loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, while-loop

I'm doing a web scraping with a dynamic website that has a **"Load more"** button. Though I solve the load more problems by using a while loop. It has another challenge when I try to scrape the data it just keeps multiplying. So the first batch of data is 24 data when I scrape the second batch it also scrapes the first batch so it scrape 48 data with only 24 new data being added and soon.

heres my code.

```rb
        require "selenium-webdriver"

        driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
        url ="https://www.example.com/categories/car-parts"

        driver.navigate.to "#{url}"
        wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)

        while driver.page_source.include? "Load more"

            load_more = wait.until {
              load_more_element = driver.find_element(css: ".styles__loadMore___yYAF4")
            }
            sleep 3
            load_more.click()
            puts "load_more"
            sleep 3

            seller_url = wait.until {
          element = driver.find_elements(:css, ".desktop__itemOneFourth___2t71A .styles__link___9msaS:nth-child(1)")

        }
            seller_url.each do |line|
                seller_uri = line.attribute("href")
                seller_hand = seller_uri[/https:\/\/www.example.com(.*\/([.\w+]+))/i]

                seller_handle =  seller_hand.gsub("https://www.example.com/", "")

                seller = Seller.new
                seller.seller_url = seller_uri
                seller.seller_handle = seller_handle

                seller.save
                puts seller_handle
            end

            puts seller_url.size
            sleep 3
```

What I want is that i continues to load but i want to scrape the last loaded batch minus all the previous batch.

Comment: Kind of a shot in the dark without a working example, but a couple of questions come to mind.  Is there a limit to the number of times that "Load More" is displayed or can be clicked?  Otherwise, it's an infinite loop.  And why not collect/map the first 24 links or data into an array, then click "Load More", and append the next 24 links/data into the array?  Repeat til whenever you want to break...

Answer (score 0):

You know how many records are loaded each time you hit the load more button so you can easily access only new records in the `seller_url` array:

```rb
items_per_page = 24

while driver.page_source.include? "Load more"
  # ...

  seller_url = wait.until {
    element = driver.find_elements(:css, ".desktop__itemOneFourth___2t71A .styles__link___9msaS:nth-child(1)")
  }

  seller_url.last(items_per_page).each do |line|
    # do stuff
  end

  pages_loaded += 1
end
```